# Webview pass value to SAPUI5 controller

Tags: java, android, webview, sapui5

I want to call a method (and pass parameters) from one of my sapui5 controllers via the android webview which renders the site. I've been using:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:myJavaScriptFunc('" + argumentPassingIn + "')");
```

before but the problem here is that my method have to be in the HTML like so:

```
<body>
  <h1>Body</h1>
  <script>
    myJavaScriptFunc(val){
      //Do something with val
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

in my case I want to call it from a specific controller of my SAPUI5 web app. How can I target the controller and that specific method? Anyone facing such a wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the methods of a controller are in the global (i.e. `window`) scope. Therefore I would use the [event bus](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.EventBus).

Let's say your controller has defined a method `myTestFunction`. In the `onInit` of your controller do

```
var oEventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
oEventBus.subscribe("AndroidWebView", "AndroidWebEvent", this.myTestFunction, this);
```

Then you can call the following code in your android webview

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish('AndroidWebView', 'AndroidWebEvent', { arg: '" + argumentPassingIn + "' })");
```

Comment: @Mark what about my app address "webview.loadUrl("javascript:sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish('AndroidWebView', 'AndroidWebEvent', { arg: '" + argumentPassingIn + "' })"); " on which IP is it going to try to load ?

Comment: The IP of the current web page? I would have assumed that webview.loadUrl does the same thing as when you open up chrome dev tools and execute JS in the console. It should run in the same context as the app.